# Select in Select using parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a query like the following (shortened and renamed for simplicity)

```
SELECT
  SOME_COLUMN AS value1,
  SOME_COMMON_ID as commonID,
  SOME_TAG as tagID,
  SOME_TIMESTAMP as endTime,
  ( SELECT
      SOME_TIMESTAMP AS beginTime
    FROM
      EVENTLIST
    WHERE
      EVENTLIST.SOME_TAG = 'BEGIN'
      AND EVENTLIST.SOME_COMMON_ID = commonID /* <-- Invalid column name commonID */
  ),
  endTime - beginTime AS duration
FROM
  EVENTLIST
JOIN
  (...some irrelevant lookups on other tables)
WHERE
  (...some criteria...)
```

What I would like to achieve:

This table logs some events, the time on which the event occurs is stored in `SOME_TIMESTAMP`. Several events are grouped by a common identifier called `SOME_COMMON_ID`. The type of the event is stored in `SOME_TAG`

For each of the events I would like to select the duration of the current event since the event having the tag `BEGIN`

How to achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: It's okay to calculate the difference somewhere else. However, how can I select the inner query? I changed the question to describe the problem more exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was even easier than I thought.

```
SELECT
  SOME_COLUMN AS value1,
  SOME_COMMON_ID as commonID,
  SOME_TAG as tagID,
  SOME_TIMESTAMP as endTime,
  ( SELECT
      DATEDIFF(SECOND, e2.SOME_TIMESTAMP, e1.SOME_TIMESTAMP) AS duration
      /* ^-- calc the diff here, not in the outer query */
    FROM
      EVENTLIST e2
    WHERE
      e2.SOME_TAG = 'BEGIN'
      AND e2.SOME_COMMON_ID = e1.SOME_COMMON_ID /* <-- qualify table names */
  )
FROM
  EVENTLIST e1 /* <-- name required */
JOIN
  (...some irrelevant lookups on other tables)
WHERE
  (...some criteria...)
```

I had to qualify the tables and calculate the difference right in the inner query.
And I have to calculate the difference in the inner query, so even that is possible.

Comment: This is likely to be quite slow, owing to the subselect.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That's bad luck =) I'm not going to execute this on a billions of records.

Comment: If you're not too far in, try it with the join method. Assuming `SOME_COMMON_ID` has an index, you should get excellent performance.

Answer (score 1):

Lets create some test data

```
DECLARE @EventList TABLE
(
    SOME_COLUMN_ID int,
    SOME_COLUMN varchar(20),
    SOME_TAG varchar(20),
    SOME_TIMESTAMP datetime
)

INSERT INTO @EventList
( SOME_COLUMN_ID, SOME_COLUMN, SOME_TAG, SOME_TIMESTAMP )
VALUES
( 1, 'Exporting', 'BEGIN', DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETDATE()) ),
( 1, 'Exporting', 'GOING', DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()) ),
( 1, 'Exporting', 'STILL_GOING', DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE()) ),
( 1, 'Exporting', 'GONE', DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE()) ),
( 1, 'Exporting', 'END', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) ),
( 2, 'Parsing1', 'BEGIN', DATEADD(HOUR, -5, GETDATE()) ),
( 2, 'Parsing2', 'GOING', DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()) ),
( 2, 'Parsing3', 'STILL_GOING', DATEADD(HOUR, -3, GETDATE()) ),
( 2, 'Parsing4', 'GONE', DATEADD(HOUR, -2, GETDATE()) );
```

Now I'm going to make a CTE to order the events by time and partitioned by the ID

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOME_COLUMN_ID ORDER BY SOME_TIMESTAMP) RN
    FROM @EventList
)
```

Now we are going to pull in all the events finding the one after and get the duration of each step, I also check to see if the process hit the END, otherwise I use the time now to find the duration.

```
SELECT 
    T1.SOME_COLUMN_ID,
    T1.SOME_COLUMN,
    T1.SOME_TAG,
    T1.SOME_TIMESTAMP AS BeginTime,
    (CASE WHEN t1.SOME_TAG != 'END' THEN ISNULL(t2.SOME_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE()) ELSE NULL END) EndTime,
    (CASE WHEN t1.SOME_TAG != 'END' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t1.SOME_TIMESTAMP, ISNULL(t2.SOME_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE())) ELSE NULL END) Duration
FROM T t1
LEFT JOIN T t2
    ON t1.SOME_COLUMN_ID = t2.SOME_COLUMN_ID
    AND t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
```

Here is the output:

```
SOME_COLUMN_ID  SOME_COLUMN SOME_TAG     BeginTime                  EndTime              Duration
1               Exporting   BEGIN        2014-12-18 05:31:06.090    2014-12-18 06:31:06.090 60
1               Exporting   GOING        2014-12-18 06:31:06.090    2014-12-18 07:31:06.090 60
1               Exporting   STILL_GOING  2014-12-18 07:31:06.090    2014-12-18 08:31:06.090 60
1               Exporting   GONE         2014-12-18 08:31:06.090    2014-12-18 09:31:06.090 60
1               Exporting   END          2014-12-18 09:31:06.090    NULL    NULL
2               Parsing1    BEGIN        2014-12-18 05:31:06.090    2014-12-18 06:31:06.090 60
2               Parsing2    GOING        2014-12-18 06:31:06.090    2014-12-18 07:31:06.090 60
2               Parsing3    STILL_GOING  2014-12-18 07:31:06.090    2014-12-18 08:31:06.090 60
2               Parsing4    GONE         2014-12-18 08:31:06.090    2014-12-18 10:31:06.090 120
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the subselect to get the `BEGIN` time into a `JOIN`, you'll more easily get around the column naming issue, as well as probably gain some performance.

Using your current pattern, the timestamp calculation would need to occur at a higher level of query nesting because the aliases assigned to the subselect value and regular table value are not available for use inside the `SELECT` at the same query level. That's also solved by using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  curevt.SOME_COLUMN AS value1,
  curevt.SOME_COMMON_ID as commonID,
  curevt.SOME_TAG as tagID,
  curevt.SOME_TIMESTAMP as endTime,
  beginevt.SOME_TIMESTAMP AS beginTime,
  -- In the JOIN scenario, the calc can happen here, without using the alias
  curevt.SOME_TIMESTAMP - beginevt.SOME_TIMESTAMP AS duration
FROM 
  -- The table first for current events
  EVENTLIST curevt
  -- Join against itself for the BEGIN events
  INNER JOIN EVENTLIST beginevt 
    -- Join condition on SOME_COMMON_ID and also the BEGIN event
    ON curevt.SOME_COMMON_ID = beginevt.SOME_COMMON_ID
    AND beginevt.SOME_TAG = 'BEGIN'
```

Here's an example, using `DATEDIFF()` to find minutes difference with `datetime` columns. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b02ac/7, though it sounds like you may have something different like Unix timestamps. Make your calculation accordingly, the concept is the same either way.

Note: if you will have some values of `SOME_COMMON_ID` with no corresponding `BEGIN` event, you would need to use a `LEFT JOIN` here instead of an `INNER JOIN` to ensure they show in the result set. You might also need to handle the `duration` calculation a little differently with an `IFNULL()` or similar, because it would be `NULL`.